# Cannot read property of undefined in angular2

Tags: angular, ionic2

I am using Angular 2 and am making an API call to get back some JSON. The call works and I get a response.

```
export class DetailsPage {

  public userID;
  v: any = {};           

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public http: Http) {

    this.userID = navParams.get('userID');

    var headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');  

    let urlSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();
    let body = urlSearchParams.toString();

    this.http.get('http://api.domain.com/visitor/'+this.userID, {headers:headers}).map(res => res.json()).subscribe(data => {
        this.v = data.res;
    }); 

  }

}
```

Within my template I have:

```
<pre>{{v | json}}</pre>
```

And this shows me my JSON ...

```
{
  "user": {
    "id": "794149",
    "tag_name": "",
    "tag_id": "0",
    "tag_style": {
      "color": null,
      "font": null,
      "style": "label-default"
    }
  },
```

But how can I display the user's ID?

I have tried ..

```
{{ v.user.id }}
```

But this gives me an error:

```
Error in ./DetailsPage class DetailsPage -  caused by: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To bind to a property on an object can be null use the safe navigation operator ["?"](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#safe-navigation-operator).

```
   {{v?.user?.id}}
```

Comment: That works! How come though? I know v.user.id exists. Is it the case that at the point when the template first loads then this isn't defined but a fraction of a second later it does exist but previously it was too late and the error had already been thrown?

Comment: @Chris, yup - that's it